# how to revert the changes of a text box

Tags: javascript, textbox

I am loading the values of a text box on page load and there would be a button next to the text box.

If i change the value of the text box and if I click on the button then the text box should load the values of the text box when it was loaded first time(its like reverting the changes made to the text box)

**Edit** Code added from self-answer below...

here is my code :

```
function revertTextValue() {
  alert("gamesUrl :") alert(gamesUrl${i});
  var x = document.getElementById("gamesUrl${i}").defaultValue; gamesUrl${i}.value=x;
}
```

what might have gone wrong in specifying `gamesUrl${i}`, I know something is missed here....

Comment: What is a "text box"? Is this java? Are you sure?

Comment: looking at the tags, I would guess textbox, javascript

Comment: text box in gsp(grails page). any html, javascript or grails help would be great

Comment: Java tag removed, Javascript tag added. Original poster, please don't confuse the two languages as they are very different, as different as ham is to hamster.

Comment: Indeed - I've deleted my answer, as I have no idea how feasible it would be in Javascript.

Comment: You will need to save the `textarea`'s (or `input type="text"`) content `onload` into a variable that your button then would call to reinstate it, or use AJAX to reload it from the server. (Or... do a full postback, doesn't seem like what you want though.)

Comment: @JonSkeet - It's fairly feasible with the limited information available, or just by saving it with an `onload` action. It could be done with an AJAX request, for instance. Would have been interesting to see your answer. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery you can use the following code:

#### HTML

```
<input name="username" id="username" data-default-value="Default value" value="Default value"/>
<a href="#" id="revert">REVERT</a>
```

#### JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(){
    $('#revert').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#username').val($('#username').data('default-value'));
    });
});
```

Here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/z5KGt/) for this code. If you are using any other library, it can be done in a similar manner.

Comment: thanks for the response, i am using grails and javascript in my pages

Comment: whether this can be done in javascript( i mean whether this code will be supported by javascript?

Comment: If I'm not completely wrong, Grails ships with the PrototypeJS library. I'm no expert in prototype so I can not provide you with a code sample. Of course this task can be done in plain javascript, too, but event handling and dom manipulation are those tasks, which are made much easier with a JS library.

Comment: js is not reading the value of gamesUrl${i}, please let me know how to implement that in code <td><g:textField name="gamesUrl${i}" id="gamesUrl${i} data-default-value="${moreGamesUrls.get(country.key)}" value="${moreGamesUrls.get(country.key)}" /></td>
<td><input type="button" name="revert${i}" value="Revert" onClick="revertTextValue()" /></td>

function revertTextValue() {

alert("gamesUrl :")
alert(gamesUrl${i});

var x = document.getElementById("gamesUrl${i}").defaultValue;
gamesUrl${i}.value=x;

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [defaultValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/defaultValue) property of the textbox.

**EDIT** after comment:

change `onClick="revertTextValue()` to `onClick="revertTextValue(event)`, it is easier to pass the reference of the element than playing with `id`

With the function changed to something like:

```
function revertTextValue(ev){
  ev = ev || window.event;
  var inp = ev.target || ev.srcElement;
  inp.value = inp.defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: my code looks like below...please let me know how to use the defaultvalue

Comment: <g:each in="${countries}" status="i" var="country">
                            <tr colspan="3">
                                <td>${country.value}</td>
                                <td><g:textField name="gamesUrl${i}" value="${moreGamesUrls.get(country.key)}" /></td>
                                <td><input type="button" name="revert${i}" value="Revert" onClick="revertTextValue(gamesUrl${i})" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </g:each>

Comment: <td><g:textField name="gamesUrl${i}" id="gamesUrl${i} data-default-value="${moreGamesUrls.get(country.key)}" value="${moreGamesUrls.get(country.key)}" /></td>
<td><input type="button" name="revert${i}" value="Revert" onClick="revertTextValue()" /></td>

function revertTextValue() {

alert("gamesUrl :")
alert(gamesUrl${i});

var x = document.getElementById("gamesUrl${i}").defaultValue;
gamesUrl${i}.value=x;

}

Comment: hi Mic, thanks for the response, i have implemented the default value, still its not working for me...please see below my code once again

Comment: anything wrong in this <td><g:textField name="gamesUrl${i}" id="gamesUrl${i}" data-default-value="${moreGamesUrls.get(country.key)}" value="${moreGamesUrls.get(country.key)}" /></td>
       <td><input type="button" name="revert${i}" value="Revert" onClick="revertTextValue(this)" /></td>

Comment: Hi Mic, when i gave "this" as a parameter, its sending the value "Revert" to the java script method, not the text box value through it.